# Devise not redirecting where I would expect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

Just migrated from Authlogic to Devise, and having a redirect issue.
I have the following:

```
  root :to => "welcome#index"

  authenticated :user do
    root :to => "dashboard#show"
  end
```

However, after loggin in, I end up on welcome#index, and not on dashboard#show as I would expect.

The [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) documentation says:

> After signing in a user, confirming the account or updating the
>   password, Devise will look for a scoped root path to redirect.
>   Example: For a :user resource, it will use user_root_path if it
>   exists, otherwise default root_path will be used.

Which only reinforces my expectation.

Comment: Are you sure that your devise model is *user*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
     new_order_path 

end
```

Define this in your applications controller. This will route your user to a particular path after sign_in.

Additional tidbit:

If you want to route the user to a particular page after confirming through email use this in your applications controller.

```
  def after_confirmation_path_for(resource_or_scope)

  end
```

---

Try this:

```
resources :dashboard

authenticated :user do
  root :to => "dashboard#show"
end
```

make sure the

```
root :to => "path"
```

after the above code and not below that.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain why this method is necessary? should it not default to root_path, and therefore work as I have it?

Comment: Not sure about that. I have never used the method that you have used, I've always used this way.

Comment: My method serves a different purpose, it allows your root url to render different pages depending on whether you are logged in or not.

Comment: It appears it was the ordering that was causing the problem! made sure root :to => "path" came last, and all started working. Thanks

Comment: Why does it have to be in that order? I didn't see anything in the documentation that mentioned that.

Comment: this is not a problem with devise. This will happen with any other route to. It should know which route to give preference to.